# Why and when to create custom controller factory?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I understand how to create a custom controller factory, but I wonder what is the exact need of creating custom controller factory? I tried google. The response are:

1. When not to have the "Controller" appended controller name. (Makes no sense to write a whole new controller factory because of this reason)
2. When there is need of Dependency Injection in controller constructor. But this can also be achieved using a parameterized controller along with the default one.

Can someone help explaining with example?

Comment: You could find an answer at http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=878

Answer (score 0):

The CustomControllerFactory can help you to plug external controllers to your MVC project, for example i use in a project the custom controller made with MEF framework ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/dd460648%28v=vs.110%29.aspx )